# I can't get sys.exit() to work. (Link to Code below)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to have a button exit the code, and have a print statement to test that it's working. The statement prints, but does not exit. What do I do?

https://github.com/Jpaylaycoderguy/Code
Code in project.py

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question would be more easily answered if you included a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
turtle.bye()
```

instead. It will raise a Terminator exception. If you don't like the red error message, use

```
try:
    draw_square()

    while True:
        wn.update()
except turtle.Terminator:
    pass
```